# Android Change orientation on deviceanywhere

Tags: android, orientation, device, landscape

How can I change the orientation to landscape while testing the app on deviceanywhere? I tried to right-click on the device, and click on Controls -> Turn left, that turned the phone, but my app did not orient to landscape. My app works well for rotation on the actual device.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: If I remember correctly there's an orientation option inside Device Anywhere. It should be on the right hand side where the other options are.

Comment: Yes, tried that too, it just turns the phone left, but my app still does not change orientation!

Comment: Actually, its not just my app, when I change the orientation field under "Hardware", even the phone's menu etc. do not change to landscape orientation!

Answer (score 1):

Under Hardware, click "Close Flip Phone". That should rotate to landscape.

[Here](http://www.deviceanywhere.com/userfiles/file/documentation/DeviceAnywhere_User_Manual.pdf) is some more info. You can find more detailed info on page 22.

This may be for an older version..